# How do I make rails' logger use ANSI sequences when outputting to screen, but not when logging to a file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging, ansi-colors

I was annoyed with having to cut way through ANSI sequences in a log on production server (`log/production.log`), so I added `config.colorize_logging = false` to `config/environments/production.rb`. But now when I run a console (`bin/rails c`), the output is not colorized as well. Why is it so? Is there a way to make logger use ANSI sequences when outputting to screen, and not use them when logging to a file?

**UPD** What I was able to figure out. When `rails` app starts, it [creates `logger`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.0/railties/lib/rails/application/bootstrap.rb#L33-56) to log into a file:

```
Rails.logger ||= config.logger || begin
  path = config.paths["log"].first
  unless File.exist? File.dirname path
    FileUtils.mkdir_p File.dirname path
  end

  f = File.open path, 'a'
  f.binmode
  f.sync = config.autoflush_log # if true make sure every write flushes

  logger = ActiveSupport::Logger.new f
  logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
  logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
  logger
rescue StandardError
  logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDERR))
  logger.level = ActiveSupport::Logger::WARN
  logger.warn(
    "Rails Error: Unable to access log file. Please ensure that #{path} exists and is writable " +
    "(ie, make it writable for user and group: chmod 0664 #{path}). " +
    "The log level has been raised to WARN and the output directed to STDERR until the problem is fixed."
  )
  logger
end
```

And then [attaches to it another logger](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.0/railties/lib/rails/commands/server.rb#L138-146) to output messages to `STDOUT`:

```
def log_to_stdout
  wrapped_app # touch the app so the logger is set up

  console = ActiveSupport::Logger.new($stdout)
  console.formatter = Rails.logger.formatter
  console.level = Rails.logger.level

  Rails.logger.extend(ActiveSupport::Logger.broadcast(console))
end
```

For some reason, breaking with `byebug` keyword at [`ActiveSupport::Logger#initialize`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.0/activesupport/lib/active_support/logger.rb#L45) never succeed when I ran `./bin/rails c`.

**UPD** Okay, the culprit was `spring`, `console` (or should I say `activerecord`) creates its logger [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.0/activerecord/lib/active_record/railtie.rb#L57-62):

```
console do |app|
  require "active_record/railties/console_sandbox" if app.sandbox?
  require "active_record/base"
  console = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDERR)
  Rails.logger.extend ActiveSupport::Logger.broadcast console
end
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to switch colorized_logging on in console would be to set it explicitly to true as follows:

```
$ bin/rails c
:001 > Rails.application.config.colorize_logging
 => false 
:002 > Rails.application.config.colorize_logging = true 
 => true
:003 > Rails.application.config.colorize_logging
 => true
```

There might be a way to set this automatically every time the console is loaded by customizing the console with a `.irbrc` file

Comment: This setting solves nothing. If I enable it in console, sql queries are getting logged with ANSI sequences. The point is to make `logger` colorize output when outputting to screen, but not when logging to a file. The same output goes simultaneously to both screen and a file.